# Unrecognized VM option 'UseFastAccessorMethods'

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, corretto

I am running java application and get this error:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option AggressiveOpts was deprecated in version 11.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
> Unrecognized VM option 'UseFastAccessorMethods'
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: `UseFastAccessorMethods` option is [harmful](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6385687) and has been [removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8003426) in JDK 9. You need to delete this option from run configuration.

Comment: And when you are at it, remove all the other options too.